# Deploy multiple angular 4 projects using pm2

Tags: node.js, angular, pm2

I have two angular 4 projects. I have taken the build using the following command:

```
ng build
```

Now i need to deploy these projects using pm2. I was able to deploy 1 project using the following command:

```
pm2 start /usr/bin/ng -- serve
```

But when i try the same command to deploy the second project I am getting the following error:

```
[PM2][ERROR] Script already launched, add -f option to force re-execution
```

Is there a way to run two instance of ng at the same time?

Comment: The serve command is not recommended for live deployments btw. Also, if you try and run it twice without specifying a port, both instances will try to run on port 4200, which will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give meaningful names to your started projects:

```
pm2 start --name "first-project" /usr/bin/ng -- serve
pm2 start --name "other-project" /usr/bin/ng -- serve
```

However, I'm concerned you're using pm2 to *deploy* Angular applications.
Angular is deployable in production by serving the .html, .css and .js files ; you don't need a server to handle that.

Comment: Wow! Just what I was looking for ! Thanks.

Comment: This was part of a client requirement. That's why I am using a server for deployment.

Comment: Do not use `ng serve` as a mean to serve/host your application on **production**. The CLI warns you of the same. ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274